# Paypal Adapative Payment - IPN and Successful return response

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing an application that requires to use Paypal Adaptive payments. I am using .net mvc framework and c# for development

As per the requirement of an application, I have to take a pre-approval of an user to deduct an amount by certain future date.

I am using https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_preapprove_payment/dotnet?success=true this guide to develop my solution.

There is no problem till step 3 - redirecting user to paypal to authorise pre-approval.

I would like to know how to implement IPN so I will get notified that user has authorised us for pre-approval. But there is no guide or information regarding what kind of object it will return to an IPN method. And even when user successfully authorise for pre-approval, user is being redirected to the returnUrl but there is no response coming back with it.

Any idea, direction or guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [IPN - Getting Started](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)
- [IPN - Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)
- [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/)
- If you're using the [PayPal Adaptive Payments Classic SDK for .NET](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-dotnet), then you can use [`IPNMessage.Validate()`](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/Source/SDK/IPNMessage.cs#L106) to validate a received IPN message.

Comment: I am using RestAPI ... Above link doesn't say what kind of response object that will be returned by POST IPN call makes by Paypal site. There is a sample format given but it has all discrete parameters as a part of url then how would I know what will be values are useful and what are not ...

Comment: @microchip78 your question indicated you're using Adaptive Payments, which is not yet available in the REST API.  If you're using REST payments, then you'll want to look at the [Webhook](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/) documentation.  As for seeing what the IPN format looks like that PayPal will send for a specific event, I'd recommend checking out the IPN Simulator in combination with a site like [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/).

Comment: I think you may be right. I am not able to find IPN documentation specific for adaptive payment Rest API. I will try using webhook and see if that works.